# UIImageView Image Disappears With Certain UIImageOrientations

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics, uiimageorientation

Working through a Core Graphics tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift

Theres one part where you need to preserve the UIImageOrientation (of course!). However I'm noticing something VERY quirky and I'm not sure what the cause is.

Here is the code block

```
  @IBAction func amountSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

        let sliderValue = sender.value

        filter.setValue(sliderValue, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        let outputImage = filter.outputImage;
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: filter.outputImage.extent())

        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg, scale:1, orientation: UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored)
       //  let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
        println("New image is \(newImage)")
        self.imageView.image = newImage
    }
```

When I change the image to certain rotations, say Up, the image appears. However when I change to right or left it moves outside the UIImageView (and if I set the scale up really high I can see parts of it coming back on the screen).

I am not rotating the UIImageView, only the UIImage. Before, when I was doing this in Objective-C I never had this issue. I would just set the UIImage rotation and it would always be 0,0 in the UIImageView.

Using Swift (or perhaps something else?) seems to result in different behaviour.

Can you think of any reason why rotating the image moves it way from the its 0,0 of its UIImageView, and what I can do fix that?

Thanks!